# Is it necessary to encrypt nonce in cryptographic communication?

Tags: encryption, nonce

Server and client have a pre-shared key K. Assuming that that pre-shared key is safe, so nobody other than server/client can encrypt/decrypt.

Client sends a nonce N to server, server then sends back message M in encrypted form AES_CBC_Encrypt(M+N, K, IV) to client. So client can verify if there is a replay attack trying to send an expired message.

Is it necessary for client to send N in encrypted form AES_CBC_Encrypt(N, K, IV) or it is OK to just send N in clear.

(M and N are 16-byte array, M+N means concatenation of M and N).

Comment: Just sending "N in clear" would completely fail to protect against replays.

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Ricky, how would it? (given the attacker does not know M or K?)

Comment: Just sending N in clear would make the rest of what gets sent completely independent of N.

Comment: Your notation appears to indicate you would reuse a pair K/IV pair for the second encryption. Independent of the answer to this, *never* reuse an IV with the same key.

Comment: Assume, for the sake of argument, that M is exactly one AES block in length. CBC ciphertexts are malleable, so an attacker can trivially garble the component of the ciphertext  containing the nonce. If you don't check that the nonce is one that you have previously sent (and not simply one you haven't seen before), an attacker will be able to replay any message he pleases. You *may* want to a) use CTR and have an incrementing IV and no nonce, b) use an AEAD mode like GCM with the nonce as the AAD instead of part of the plaintext, or c) just use TLS and avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Nonces do not necessarily have to be secret, their only use is to ensure that a message is unique.

Basically, the fact that a plaintext includes a nonce means that the ciphertext is of no use to an attacker.

An attacker being able to *influence* the nonce is a different issue and will likely cause some problems in protocols that depend on it.

Comment: what is the issue of attacker being able to influence the nonce?

Comment: If they can influence the nonce during a handshake to a known nonce from a captured ciphertext then they can replay the ciphertext.

Comment: I am not doing any handshaking here though.

Comment: Having the client send a nonce, then the server responding with the encrypted message is really a handshake :) Ensure that the client actually validates the nonce and you'll be golden.

Comment: I'm having a nonce in this scenario so that the client can validate the response from server.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your second phrase. If the nonce is public and part of plaintext, then the attacker suddenly has part of the plaintext. Also, the nonce can't be part of plaintext and secret to the decrypter, because the latter can't decrypt.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru Think of it a bit like a cryptographic salt with password hashing. It's not considered a "secret", but it's appended to the plaintext before hashing and ensures the same plaintexts (e.g. the same passwords) result in different ciphertexts.

Comment: Who generates the nonce? Is it the client or the server? In my opinion, it should be the server the one doing the encryption. But I like to understand other cases